Typesafe nested function return using generics
I have a the following mapper with the type associated with, but I have no clue what to look, to type func correctly.
type Action<T, K> = {
  key: K;
  func: // What should this be?
};

type ActionMapper<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Action<T, K>;
}; 

export enum EActionSelectPot {
  CREATE_ORDER = 'CREATE_ORDER',
  ADD_ITEM = 'ADD_ITEM',
  DELETE_ORDER = 'DELETE_ORDER',
}

const first_function = () => 'hi';
const second_function = () => ['hi'];
const third_function = () => {
  hi: 'hi';
};

const test: ActionMapper<typeof EActionSelectPot> = {
  CREATE_ORDER: {
    key: EActionSelectPot.CREATE_ORDER,
    func: first_function,
  },
  ADD_ITEM: {
    key: EActionSelectPot.ADD_ITEM,
    func: second_function,
  },
  DELETE_ORDER: {
    key: EActionSelectPot.DELETE_ORDER,
    func: third_function,
  },
};

const hi = test.CREATE_ORDER.func();


My goal is pretty straightforward, I have to have an object that infer the type of the function with generics.
The problem is that I have no clue if this is possible at all, if so, is there any way to accomplish such thing.
I've tried with func: () => ReturnType[K]['func']>;, but I really don't know where to look for.
I don't want to infer manually the type of the return, can it be fully dynamic ?
Where to look for ?

• "Infer manually" doesn't make a lot of sense; do you really mean "infer" there? • TypeScript doesn't infer type arguments in a generic type, that would need ms/TS#32794. You can have it infer for generic functions, so you can write an actionMapper helper function. See this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

You are right, infer wasn't the correct word.
Your solution is working perfectly, but this is exactly what I'm not looking for.
Because you have to define your type ahead.
Is there any way to accomplish such thing ?
Creating a type like:
Record<keyof typeof test, typeof test[K]['func']>
Maybe it's not possible at all, I feel like you can do basically w/e you want in typescript.

Define what type ahead? Look at this playground link and tell me exactly what line your problem with my solution starts, and how. I'm not seeing it.

Ok you did it, that's exactly what I'm looking for, the first link you gave infer
const test: ActionMapper<{   [EActionSelectPot.CREATE_ORDER]: string,   [EActionSelectPot.ADD_ITEM]: string[],   [EActionSelectPot.DELETE_ORDER]: { hi: string } }> =
Which is redundant as you said, but the last solution you gave is really smart didn't really catch the  <T,>(a: ActionMapper<T>) => a;
Like the <T,> didn't know about this syntax

Okay, I'll write an answer when I get a chance.

The generic ActionMapper<T> type you're looking for is
type ActionMapper<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Action<K, T[K]>;
};

where Action is
type Action<K, V> = {
  key: K;
  func: () => V;
};
    

But, unfortunately, you can't ask the compiler to infer T for you in generic types. That means there's no way to write something like:
// don't do this, it won't work:
const test: ActionMapper<infer> = {
  [EActionSelectPot.CREATE_ORDER]: {
    key: EActionSelectPot.CREATE_ORDER,
    func: first_function,
  },
  [EActionSelectPot.ADD_ITEM]: {
    key: EActionSelectPot.ADD_ITEM,
    func: second_function,
  },
  [EActionSelectPot.DELETE_ORDER]: {
    key: EActionSelectPot.DELETE_ORDER,
    func: third_function,
  },
};

and have T be inferred as if you had written
const test: ActionMapper<{
  [EActionSelectPot.CREATE_ORDER]: string,
  [EActionSelectPot.ADD_ITEM]: string[],
  [EActionSelectPot.DELETE_ORDER]: { hi: string }
}> = { ⋯ };

There is a longstanding open feature request for this at microsoft/TypeScript#32794, but for now it's not part of the language. You have to work around it.

The standard workaround is to use generic functions to help. TypeScript will infer type arguments when you call generic functions, so you can make a function whose sole purpose is to give you that inference:
const actionMapper = <T,>(a: ActionMapper<T>) => a;

That's an identity function at runtime, it's just a => a, and so const test = actionMapper(xxx) and const test = xxx are the same at runtime. But TypeScript can use actionMapper(xxx) to guide the inference for xxx and thus for test:
const test = actionMapper({
  [EActionSelectPot.CREATE_ORDER]: {
    key: EActionSelectPot.CREATE_ORDER,
    func: first_function,
  },
  [EActionSelectPot.ADD_ITEM]: {
    key: EActionSelectPot.ADD_ITEM,
    func: second_function,
  },
  [EActionSelectPot.DELETE_ORDER]: {
    key: EActionSelectPot.DELETE_ORDER,
    func: third_function,
  },
})
test
//^? const test: ActionMapper<{
//    [EActionSelectPot.CREATE_ORDER]: string,
//    [EActionSelectPot.ADD_ITEM]: string[],
//    [EActionSelectPot.DELETE_ORDER]: { hi: string }
//   }>

That's the right type, and it was inferred for you, as desired.  And while the actionMapper function is a workaround, it's not really much different for the developer from what you wanted. Instead of const test: ActionMapper<infer> = { ⋯ } they write const test = actionMapper(⋯).
Playground link to code

Thanks for your explaination, but there are 2 things that I don't fully get.
First, why Action<K, T[K]>; and not Action<K, T[K]['func']>; how does typescript knows that you are give the func generics and not the object as a whole since T[K] should return {     key: EActionSelectPot.ADD_ITEM,     func: second_function,   }, right ?

And why <T,> and not  there is a difference, and when I remvoe the , I get syntax issues, you did some black magic there

• No, T in ActionMapper<T> is some arbitrary object type, not an ActionMapper itself; it has no func in its properties. ActionMapper<T> is a mapped type. Perhaps you are being confused by TS's ability to infer from mapped types. • Without a trailing comma the JSX parser gets confused, and unless you disable JSX/TSX, the easiest fix is to add that no-op trailing comma. You could also write <T extends unknown> or any other thing that unconfuses JSX.
